# Auto generate a view from a strongly typed class with complex types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, t4

Using the "Stock" Asp.Net MVC templates can I expect a view auto generated from a strongly typed class with a complex type to generate the display for the complex type too?

i.e.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyName { get; set;}
    public MyDetail Details { get; set; }
}

public class MyDetails
{
    public string detail1 { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: @CodeCaster .. you might notice that I retagged the question.

Comment: @tereško nevermind, thought you edited ASP.Net in the title. :-)